# <span> seems to generate white box around it that I can't remove

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a few Glyphicons around form system. Everything was looking good prior to my restart. Now I have these boxes around anything that has a `<span>`. It isn't just my computer as I checked it on a colleagues. Both of us are now at a loss. Another fun fact is that white borders appears again however they don't look too awful so they will be on the back burner.

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hbhH.png)

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJFo4.png)

Here is the code used (it is using bootstrap for style)

```html
Major<span style="color:#f0ad4e" class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span>
```

If there is any information missing I will edit it into this question for you on request.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

```js
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
WHY?<span style="color: red; font-size: x-small" class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span>
```

It annoyingly doesn't show up here as an issue.

Comment: There's no glyphicon CSS added here, it's hard to reproduce the issue. I recommend adding this CSS to your example: <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">

Please add in CSS from other pages too.

Comment: It seems fine to me. Inspect the `<span>` elements, are there border styles applied to it from any global CSS selector like `span { ... }`?

Comment: No there is nothing removing the icon works fine, I have replaced the fonts folder as well with a fresh download. I tried linking the style sheets only to receive noxious errors back from Stackoverflow. However it is an unedited version of bootstrap .

Comment: Can you deploy a live version that people can view in their browsers?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I think I will abondon the whole idea of using glyphicons and just convert it into a png. Frustrating though the replacement process will be.
Thanks for your help none the less.

Comment: Can you set the border to match the background? `border: solid 1px #0275D8;`

Comment: I did try making a border of the same background colour, problem is that it continues to exist as the same white box regardless of border type colour etc etc, honestly this is one of the stupidest problems I've ever encountered.